# How can I get the name of every Facebook page separately with the Graph API?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to display all the pages the user is admin of with the new Graph API in Facebook. What I do is:

```
       $queries = '{
        "page_admin_ids" : "SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid = ' . $uid . '",
        "page_name_and_id" : "SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #page_admin_ids)"
       }';

        $data = array(
            'method' => 'fql.multiquery', 
            'queries' => $queries,
            'callback'  => ''
        );

        $fqlResult = $facebook->api($data);
        print_r($fqlResult);
```

This code works and all the data of the Array are displayed in an Array format. I want to use each of them, each of the page name, separately and add it to my html code. How can I get the first element for example of the results?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the new Facebook PHP SDK then you should be able to do the following:

```
<?php
$facebook  = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $config['appid'],
    'secret' => $config['appsecret'],
    'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
$user = null;
if ($session) {
    try {
        $user = $facebook->api('/me');
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
}
if (!$user) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'canvas' => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'req_perms' => 'manage_pages', // request extended perms. here
        'next' => "http://www.example.com/",
        'cancel_url' => "http://www.example.com/",
    ));
    echo '<fb:redirect url="' . $loginUrl . '" />';
}

$pages = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
...
```

This gives me a list of pages I'm an administrator of on Facebook.

Comment: Mmm no it didn't work although I am using the new PHP SDK. Maybe my question was not that clear and this "accounts" is for something else?. Anyway I found a way to do it. I used a for loop and then this one:
$fqlResult[1]['fql_result_set'][$i]['name']

So I managed to get all of my pages but one by one. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: As I understood this thing could be worked if I am adding also manage_pages permissions right? Could you explain me how can I do this?

Comment: You would need to request the permission when you're setting up Facebook. I've edited my above answer to incorporate an example of this...

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Something more.
When I am posting a message to one of my pages, on the wall, my admin name is shown. For example "Novellino says hello.." although I would like to use the page name: "MyPage say hello". I read somewhere that I need to use this manage_pages you said but I haven't really understand how to change this name. Is this something possible?

Comment: Ok I found it through this link http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10005
Thanks anyway!